# Rails 3.2.5 with Foundation. Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I managed to install foundation using their steps on their website

```
  http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/rails.php
```

I have followed their steps carefully and managed to get my homepage with the orbit image scroller working. However if i try and work with the javascript Reveal or Clearing components, they do not seem to work. I get no error in my console when debugging.

Has anyone come across this or have any idea why this could be happening.

My application.js looks like this

```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require foundation/app
   //= require foundation
   //= require_tree .
```

My source looks like this

```
<!-- Included CSS Files -->
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/foundation/globals.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/foundation/typography.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/foundation/grid.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/foundation/ui.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/foundation/forms.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/foundation/orbit.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/foundation/reveal.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/foundation/mobile.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/foundation/index.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/landing.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/layouts/layout.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Included JS Files -->
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/app.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/modernizr.foundation.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/jquery.reveal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/jquery.orbit-1.4.0.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/jquery.customforms.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/jquery.placeholder.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/jquery.tooltips.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/index.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/landing.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```